# How to write <noscript> tag in html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app.html.erb and I need to add noscript tag in it. Like for adding a script tag we do something like

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>

<% end %>
```

I am not able to figureout how to write noscript tag in html.erb. Please help me.

```
<noscript> 
 <iframe src="googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=#{key}" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<noscript> 
  <iframe src="googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=<%= key %>" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

ERb will interpret things in `<%= %>` as ruby, so this would asume there's a variable `key` that was passed into the erb.